# Whitelist validation of URI and $_POST global variable at the start of the script to enforce strict security

Tags: php, validation, security

I am working on a PHP framework with strict security in mind. The idea is to enforce whitelist validation at the top of the routing script so only acceptable characters can be typed in the URI (which would include the $_GET global variable as well), and in the $_POST global variable.

The focus is security and I am willing to compromise limiting the number of character inputs, as opposed to blacklist validation. My code can be found below.

Would there be another simpler way to do whitelist validation of the URI and $_POST variable in PHP at the start of the script? The only other scripts running before the routing file is the config and functions files, which do not do routing.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allow only alphanumeric and GET request characters on the Request URI
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\/\?\&\=\-]/i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {

    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 400 Bad Request");
    exit('<h1>The URI should only contain alphanumeric and GET request characters.</h2>');

}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allow only whitelisted characters in $_POST global variable array.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

if (isset($_POST) && preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\/\?\&\=\-\.]/i', implode('/', $_POST)) ) {

    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 400 Bad Request");
    exit('<h1>Submitted data should only contain whitelisted characters.</h1>');

}
```